# Precise definition of sierpinski triangle

Tags: measure-theory, fractals

I have a problem, where I am asked to give a precise definition of the Sierpinski-triangle. The problem describes the usual algorithm to construct the triangle. However, I am clueless on how I should give a different definition.

Is there some definition using the union of the points of the Sierpinski-triangle?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what you might mean by "the usual algorithm". Without further information, I can only guess that you are expected to turn "the usual algorithm" into a precise set theoretical definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:
The unique compact subset $S$ of $\mathbb C$ such that $$S=\frac 12S \cup \left(\frac12S+1\right)\cup \left(\frac12S+\frac{1+i\sqrt 3}2\right)$$

Comment: The question later asks me to prove that the lebesgue measure ist 0. I am not sure if your definition helps with that. Also what so you mean with $ 0,5  S $ ?